# DTD file needs validation

Tags: validation, dtd

I have a short dtd file and it has about 15 errors. I have to find and describe them. Maybe someone could check my tryings and validate them? Thanks a lot.

Here is the code:

`<!ENTITY % note "(tip | warning | remark)">` // there are needles brackets and spaces between "|"

`<!ENTITY % content "(#PCDATA | icon | menu | ref | iconbmp)*">` //  thereare needles brackets and spaces between "|"

`<!ELEMENT topic (title, bar, procedure, bar?, %note;)>` // repeat of bar is invalid, %note; should be in brackets

`<!ATTLIST topic id ID #IMPLIED>` //should be #REQUIRED instead of #IMPLIED?

`<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>` // correct

`<!ATTLIST title keyword CDATA>` // there are no description of atribute behave??

`<!ELEMENT procedure (step+)>` // correct

`<!ELEMENT step (action, (%note;)*>` // there are no bracket after "*"

`<!ELEMENT action %content;>` // %content; should be in brackets

`<!ELEMENT tip %content;>` // %content; should be in brackets

`<!ATTLIST tip for (amateur|expert) "amateur">` // correct

`<!ELEMENT warning % note;>` // needles  space between "%", and "note",  %note; should be in brackets

`<!ELEMENT remark %note;>` // wyrazenie %note; should be in brackets

`<!ELEMENT icon (#PCDATA)>` // correct

`<!ELEMENT menu (#PCDATA | shortcut)+>` // needles  spaces between "|"

`<!ELEMENT ref (#PCDATA)>` // correct

`<!ATTLIST ref link idref #REQUIRED>` // ref and link should be reversed? and #IMPLIED instead of #REQUIRED ?

`<!ELEMENT shortcut (#PCDATA)>` // correct

`<!ELEMENT tip (#PCDATA)>` // correct

`<!ELEMENT iconbmp EMPTY>`  // correct

`<!ATTLIST iconbmp src ENTITY #REQUIRED type NOTATION (bmp | gif | jpeg) "gif">` // needles spaces betweeen "|" , bmp instead of gif?

Comment: You might be better off at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) with this request.

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessary brackets are not an error in a DTD.

White space is not an error in a DTD.  Many readers find it makes the declaration more readable.

It is not an error to put brackets in the parameter entity replacement text instead of putting them around the parameter entity reference.

Some of the properties you identify as errors are semantic issues, not syntactic issues; they may or may not be errors, depending on the actual requirements for the DTD.

In some, some of what you identify as errors are in fact errors; most are not.  And you've missed the syntactic error in the element declaration for 'menu'.